# reading a large file using cats stream scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats, scala-streams

Reading a large text file (with 40M+ lines) and doing some operations on this list and writing the output to new file.

Ex: call a web service & use the response to do union or intersection with this list (repeat few hundred times this process)

what is the best way to implement this in a functional way using scala using cats or scala stream library(without having OOM issue)?

1. Read data in chunks
2. Do operations with current list (union or
   intersection)
3. Write to a new file

Comment: https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2-cats. Could help with #1 and #3.  Readme example is somewhat close to what you are asking.  How big is the web service query?  I assume it also needs to be streamed?

Comment: Thank you, I did understand the `scalaz-stream`.is there any resources for cat streams or examples for cat streams.
for web service, the query can be handled in memory.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I meant to paste this https://functional-streams-for-scala.github.io/fs2/.   The 0.10 version of fs2 is all cats based.  The example on that page reads in a file and writes it to disk using streams.